# Strange failures in ExtJS MVC

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Using ExtJS v4.1 MVC, I have an application class that includes the following code:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'SHOP',
appFolder: 'shop',
     ...
```

and my main viewport has the following code and items:

```
requires: ['SHOP.view.CategoryKey'],
requires: ['SHOP.view.ProductLister'],
     ...

            layout: {
            type: 'border',
            padding: 3
        },
        items: [{
            region: 'west',
            title: 'TEST1',
            xtype: 'CategoryKey'
        },{
            region: 'center',
            title: 'TEST2',
            border: false
        }]
```

Note that my viewport is *not* using the ProductLister object (yet. Please bear with me).

For some completeness, below is the code for the ProductLister. Note that this is just some basic stuff that is intended to put a View into my application.

```
Ext.define('SHOP.view.ProductLister', {
extend: 'Ext.view.View',
alias: 'widget.productimages',
title: 'List Test'
});
```

I am seeing two really weird things. First, when I put the requires statement in the order shown above, when I attempt to display the page I get the following failure (running using debug):

> TypeError: name is undefined

but if I change the *order* of the requires statements, so that it looks like below:

```
    requires: ['SHOP.view.ProductLister'],
requires: ['SHOP.view.CategoryKey'],
```

the error goes away!

The second weird thing I am seeing is that when I actually change the item list so that the center has my ProductLister:

```
            layout: {
            type: 'border',
            padding: 3
        },
        items: [{
            region: 'west',
            title: 'TEST1',
            xtype: 'CategoryKey'
        },{
            region: 'center',
            xtype: 'productimages'
        }]
```

I get the same failure:

> TypeError: name is undefined

I also monitored the loading of files and noticed that in all cases the ProductLister.js file is never loaded!

A few other facts:

1. The MVC application has the standard set of directories, only the root is "shop" (hence the appFolder property in Application). Both the CategoryKey and the ProductLister class are in the view subfolder.
2. I do have a controller that lists both view classes (I eventually want to put event handling between them in the controller):

   ```
   config: {
   stores: ['Categories'],
   views: ['CategoryKey','ProductLister']
   },
   ```

In theory, between the requires statements and the configuration in the controller, both my views should be loaded. But for some reason, the ExtJS loader seems to be loading the CategoryKey.js file but not the ProductLister.js file.

Furthermore, I would assume that the order of the requires statements shouldn't matter, yet when I am not using the ProductLister object, it apparently does.

I have either found a weird bug in the MVC mechanism, or I have missed something. I am hoping that I have missed something.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening here? More importantly, what can I do to make this code work??? Am I missing a declaration somewhere? If so, where?

Someone please advise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strangest thing is that you declare the `requires` property twice, overriding the first one:

```
var o = { a:[1], a:[2] };
o.a.join(' ') === '1 2' // false
o.a.join(' ') === '2' // true
```

Try this instead:

```
requires: ['SHOP.view.ProductLister', 'SHOP.view.CategoryKey']
```

Comment: OOPS!!! I think you got it. I changed the requires property to requires: ['SHOP.view.CategoryKey','SHOP.view.ProductLister'], and that seems to have resolved the ProductLister loading problem. All my failures seem to have gone away now. Thanks...